# Head room in Socket buffer

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel

I am writing a new net device in linux kernel where i have to use socket buffer.

When i gone through the structure of the socket buffer i can see four field called `head`, `data`, `tail`, `end`. What is the purpose of Head and tail room in socket buffer.

Comment: Surely they are forming a linked list? And surely your perusal of the code is more efficient than asking here?

Answer (score 5):

Socket buffers (aka skbuffs) are passed along the network layers throughout the kernel. Meaning, they will pass from the transport layer, to the network layer and so on. The main reason for this is performance, avoiding the need for the kernel to copy and recreate the buffer each time it passes around.

This means that the skbuff data will be filled with the corresponding protocol header data as it passes through the different layers. In example, in the transport layer it might get the TCP header, on the network layer the IP header, etc.

As an optimization, linux kernel pre-allocates space for these headers and this is actually the buffer inside skbuff pointed by `head`. Now, where the data starts, meaning the first byte of the current constructed packet, is pointed by `data`. Likewise, `tail` points to the end of the current constructed packet and `end` to the end of the pre-allocated buffer.

This image might help you with my words: http://www.kernelchina.org/files/image_thumb_3_4.png

Now, it's far less computational intensive to move these pointers around and (re)build the packet the kernel is trying to send/receive, than to actually reallocate memory and copy bytes.

Comment: image link is broken!!